# gradle, how to exclude particular class in a flavor build apk

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

I have a projekt with 3 flavors for Android

1 class i need in two of the flavor but the other one should not implement it.

Is ther a way to exclude this java class for only one flavor or did i have to move the class in both other flavors and get rendundant code this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have some sources which you don't want to be compiled, Then you have to declare a filter for the sources, not for the class files.

So your gradle configuration will be look like below:

```
SetOfSources {
    main {
        java {
            include 'com/macao/somePackage/activityAdapter/**'
            include 'com/macao/someOtherPackage/**'
            exclude 'com/macao/someOtherPackage/pollingAdapter/**'
            exclude 'com/macao/someOtherPackage/matchingAdapter/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an unchangeable flavor which is called main. If you check your project file structure you will notice there is a `main` folder inside your `src` folder. This `main` folder represents your main flavor and most of your shared code should be there. Because each flavor is merging with `main`.

Then create new folders in the path where the `main` folder exists that have the same names as your flavors.

Copy both your classes to your flavors and use it by changing the build variants.